# Looking for 0.25x0.25 spatial resolution grid data for land surface temperature/precipitation

Tags: data-request, geospatial, germany, climate

I used to work with UDEL grid estimate ([look here](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/)) data where station values of monthly total raingage-measured precipitation (P) were interpolated to a `0.5 degree by 0.5 degree` latitude/longitude grid, where the grid nodes are centered on the 0.25 degree.  However, after I tried to interpolate those data with Germany `NUTS3` district only, and I got a poor match because I need to calculate population weighted yearly average for each Germany `NUTS3` polygon but some polygon lost population data which affect my expected output. Now I realized that chosen grid estimate data is not precise enough which caused this problem.

I used to work with UDEL grid estimated data with `0.5x0.5` degree resolution (http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/), but it is not ideal for my research. I used also DWD station level data ([DWD station level data link](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/)), but this dataset also won't fit my expectation.Now I am looking for a grid climate data (Temperature/precipitation data) with the better resolution.

Now I am looking for the grid climate data with better resolution, where `0.25x0.25` degree grid data of global climate (land surface temperature/precipitation) are desired. Where can I find free open source grid climate data that meet my specification? Anyone know a possible source where I can download such data? Possible help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look at ARM data. Better resolution, but unless things have changed it is not global...  https://www.arm.gov/data

Comment: @ChristopherKlaus Thanks for your prompt hit on my question. Actually, I am looking for grid level data for Germany with `0.25x0.25`degree spatial resolution. Could you give me possible help with that? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s been a decade since I’ve done research with atmospheric data. I’ll take a look later today to see what I can find.  =)

Comment: Note sure if our gap-free global time series of land surface temperature from MODIS LST data (5.6 km pixels) would be of interest: https://zenodo.org/record/1135230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Trevor-J-Smith (on GIS SE) I've found this publication in Nature's Scientific Data :

Karger, Dirk Nikolaus, Olaf Conrad, Jürgen Böhner, Tobias Kawohl, Holger Kreft, Rodrigo Wilber Soria-Auza, Niklaus E. Zimmermann, H. Peter Linder, et Michael Kessler. 2017. « Climatologies at High Resolution for the Earth’s Land Surface Areas ». Scientific Data 4 (1): 170122. https://doi.org/10.1038/sdata.2017.122.

http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata2017122

The data are described and links to download are given at the "Data Records" chapter : https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata2017122#Sec18

Following variables (among with other) are available as georeferenced TIF maps (raster data) at ~ 1km resolution :

bioclim-variable:

1=Annual Mean Temperature [°C*10]

2=Mean Diurnal Range [°C]

3=Isothermality

4=Temperature Seasonality [standard deviation]

5=Max Temperature of Warmest Month [°C*10]

6=Min Temperature of Coldest Month [°C*10]

7=Temperature Annual Range [°C*10]

8=Mean Temperature of Wettest Quarter [°C*10]

9=Mean Temperature of Driest Quarter [°C*10]

10=Mean Temperature of Warmest Quarter [°C*10]

11=Mean Temperature of Coldest Quarter [°C*10]

12=Annual Precipitation [mm/year]

13=Precipitation of Wettest Month [mm/month]

14=Precipitation of Driest Month [mm/month]

15=Precipitation Seasonality [coefficient of variation]

16=Precipitation of Wettest Quarter [mm/quarter]

17=Precipitation of Driest Quarter [mm/quarter]

18=Precipitation of Warmest Quarter [mm/quarter]

19=Precipitation of Coldest Quarter [mm/quarter]

Here is an exemple of the stylised map of Annual Mean Temperature :

[image: World map of Annual Mean Temperature [°C], for the 1981-2010 period]

You will find the code to style it this way [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19905/where-could-i-get-mean-annual-temperature-raster-or-vector-map-for-land-surfaces).

If the CHELSA dataset dont suit your needs, then for the precipitations, there are these other data :

[image: GPCC Precipitation normals in mm/year per 0.25 degree grid for year]

Rustemeier Elke, Andreas Becker, Peter Finger, Udo Schneider, et Markus Ziese. 2020. « GPCC Precipitation Climatology Version 2020 at 0.25°: Monthly Land-Surface Precipitation Climatology for Every Month and the Total Year from Rain-Gauges built on GTS-based and Historic Data: Globally Gridded Monthly Totals ». Gzip compressed NetCDF. Global Precipitation Climatology Centre (GPCC). https://doi.org/10.5676/DWD_GPCC/CLIM_M_V2020_025

Which you can access at the following link (scroll down : there are the gif and pdf versions of the files, you'll have to georeference them however) :

https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/GPCC/html/gpcc_normals_v2020_doi_download.html